# replace() for JavaScript str.endsWith("$")

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I encountered a problem in project development
I need to use regular expressions, replace, and template strings to process a string.
I found a strange problem, but I couldn't explain it myself. I made a simple demo and you can see why using different single and double quotation marks can result in different results

```js
const params = '123$';
const aa = `test(input)`;
const res1 = aa.replace(/input/g, `'${params}'`);
const res2 = aa.replace(/input/g, `"${params}"`);
console.log(res1); // test('123))
console.log(res2); // test("123$")
```

My native language is not English, so there are some grammar issues, but I can use a translator to communicate with you，thank you！

that is a issue,hava nothing to do

Comment: `$'` has a special meaning in regex replacements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, but I would also like to ask why there are different outputs in my demo for `'${params}'` and `"${params}"`,Single and double parentheses

Comment: Because ```'${params}'``` becomes `'123$'`, and `$'` has a special meaning. On the other hand, `$"` does *not* have any special meaning.

Comment: I am so sorry,I was negligent，thank you！

Answer (score 3):

`$'` has a [special meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_the_replacement) in a regex replacement string. The easiest way to work around that is to not pass a replacement *string* to `replace`, but a [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement). The return of this callback function will be used literally as is without any further interpretation of special characters:

```js
const params = '123$';
const aa = `test(input)`;
const res1 = aa.replace(/input/g, () => `'${params}'`);
const res2 = aa.replace(/input/g, () => `"${params}"`);
console.log(res1); // test('123')
console.log(res2); // test("123$")
```

Comment: Note that if you're trying to create literal Javascript code from user input here, this is still subject to all sorts of possible problems. If the user includes quote characters in `params`, the result will be invalid code. If they include some arbitrary Javascript code, you're open to code injection…

Answer (score 0):

you can modify like this

const params = "123$$";

const aa = "test(input)";

const res1 = aa.replace(/input/g, params);

Comment: Yes, this is a method, but in the requirements, this params is input by the user. Although I can first determine how to handle this $, I still hope to complete it all at once, such as using double quotes